Partially baked normals in blender
all. I got a strange problem for me. When I bake normal map it bakes only partially. And honestly I can't understand why. If I bake color texture all is ok, I have all texture that is placed on my UV. But with normals it don't works. I already recalculated normals, I tried smart UV map and result is same. It take other parts and bake it but not all mesh.



Hello please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/
